# Jupyter mix up with Python versions. Kernel uses python 3.x instead of 2.x

Tags: python-3.x, linux, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-2.x

I have an ipynb notebook written in Python 2.7 so I changed my my kernel to use Python2.

Even after changing the kernel version, it's still evidently using Python3 instead of Python2. Here is one of the errors that I get which is apparently from Python3:

```
print 'blah blah'
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The notebook metadata also shows `"version": "3.6.9"`

```
{
  "kernelspec": {
    "name": "python2",
    "display_name": "Python 2",
    "language": "python"
  },
  "language_info": {
    "name": "python",
    "version": "3.6.9",
    "mimetype": "text/x-python",
    "codemirror_mode": {
      "name": "ipython",
      "version": 3
    },
    "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
    "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
    "file_extension": ".py"
  }
}
```

I tried to edit the metadata but that does not seem to effect anything.

Here is the only related resource I found on the subject: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1689

Version info:

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.3.1
ipython          : 5.5.0
ipykernel        : 4.8.2
jupyter client   : 6.1.3
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 4.4.0
traitlets        : 4.3.2
```

Comment: Can you create a new kernel with Python2 if you haven't already done so? I use Jupyter lab and the launcher allows me to select between kernels that I have available on my system

Comment: I adjusted it through the web interface but you are right, I should try launching it using `kernel` subcommand. Do you know the command syntax to specify the kernel? I briefly tried sth like `jupyter notebook kernel=python2`  but the syntax isn't right.

Comment: Btw, I converted my code to python3 since I didn't want to invest too much time into sorting this out. This is likely some kind of bug with my jupyter version. If there are more SO users with the same issue I may spend the time to sort it out.